# IMAGE function in Google sheet rotate

Tags: google-sheets

I use `IMAGE` function to insert images from my Google drive into a sheet to key data. However, 1 particular picture, the result is rotated 90 degree. While others are exactly like they're shown in Google drive. Even the file when uploaded from my computer have the correct rotation. I tried all the parameters in the documentation but still get the same result (incorrect rotation). Is there any secret operation change the display of the file?

This is the function in Google Sheet: `=IMAGE("http://drive.google.com/uc?id="&K1,1)` 
Cell `K1` contains the file ID. The function is showing the image.
the image ID is `1L8JtTK9pwvy33lYz0GLG11JRZOfU23R7`. It's a vertical bill.

If I insert the image via script then the rotation is normal/correct.

Comment: could you provide a code you are using (in Google Sheets) for this particular image?

Comment: There is no code actually. This is the function:
`=IMAGE("http://drive.google.com/uc?id="&K1,1)`
`K1` is the file ID. The function shows the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no built in function that allow an external image to be rotated in google sheet. In this case, how about you turn the image up side down from your computer, load it to Drive, and point your K1 to that ID ?

Comment: If there isn't a built-in functionality to rotate image, how does it get rotate in the first place?

Comment: Maybe it's rotated from the beginning....

Comment: @I'-'I It's not. They are not. As I tested further with 20 images. About 5-6 of them were rotated differently, some even rotated 180 degree. And all of them were upload in the right rotation. All of them were shown in Google Drive in right rotation.

Comment: Well, FYI, I downloaded your image and open it with in my computer. Even though it looks perfectly normal on GDrive, it is rotated 90 degree in my computer. So the problem lies in the image itself. I don't have your original image, but well, it wouldn't hurt to try rotating it once, upload again, and point your K1 to that image.

Comment: I found this piece of information about image rotation [here](https://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html), which talk about an EXIF flag of images. I believe google spreadsheet's image function bypassed the EXIF flag of your image, hence the difference between GDrive and your sheet. I believe those images that has been rotated in your sheet were taken from a difference side with those in the right direction. I.E, taken as a horizontal instead of vertical photo.

Comment: Insert via code does not have the same problem. But that has some serious limitation of calling functions.